# How to validate the length of metadata in another lenguage? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im building a music player, and some tracks for some reason has some chinese characters, so when i print it in the console i get `??????` and it looks like i cant validate its length, so in the device it will cross the container [image]

this is the code that im using to validate the length:

```
<Text style = {{color: "white", fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 10}} numberOfLines = {1}>
  {
   (item.title.length > 20) ?  
   item.title.substring(0,18).padEnd(20,".") 
   : item.title
  }
</Text>
```

Comment: check that this data comes correct from your `API` because i try to print Chinese words and it gets printed fine in the console

Comment: this data its coming from the metadata of the track of my device

Comment: @Joseph im printing chinese characters in the console and i get ???